# Can't make devise after_sign_up redirection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, registration

Excuse me for this, but I can't find my error.
Here is my registrations_controller.rb code:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController  
 protected
   def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
 edit_user_registration_path(current_user)
 end
end
```

in my routes:

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
```

And redirection isn't working...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    '/an/example/path'
  end
end
```

...then adding this to your routes:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
```

All that is from [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-%28registration%29), which took about 30 minutes of searching the googles to run across that.  Was the only thing that worked for me.

**Edit:**
I might also add that after poking through the code, it doesn't look like this results in an actual redirect (despite what some docs say); I'm getting a 200 back.

Answer (score 0):

Your path should be valid (try to check `rake routes | grep registration`) otherwise you will be redirected to `root_path` or `"/"`

```
  def signed_in_root_path(resource_or_scope)
    scope = Devise::Mapping.find_scope!(resource_or_scope)
    home_path = "#{scope}_root_path"
    if respond_to?(home_path, true)
      send(home_path)
    elsif respond_to?(:root_path)
      root_path
    else
      "/"
    end
  end
```

[from Devise source code](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#L184-L194)